# Can I bind multiple variables at once?

Tags: raku, variable-binding

The following line declares a variable and *binds* it to the number on the right-hand side.

```
my $a := 42;
```

The effect is that `$a` is not a `Scalar`, but an `Int`, as can be seen by

```
say $a.VAR.^name;
```

My question is, can I bind multiple variables in one declaration? This doesn't work:

```
my ($a, $b) := 17, 42;
```

because, as can be seen using `say $a.VAR.^name`, both `$a` and `$b` are `Scalar`s now. (I think I understand why this happens, the question is whether there is a different approach that would bind both `$a` and `$b` to given `Int`s without creating `Scalar`s.)

Furthermore, is there any difference between using `:=` and `=` in this case?

Comment: You bind the left hand side to the right hand side. In the second case, you're binding a list to another. The list elements are assigned, not bound, the elements on the right hand side. Binding is not recursive. Making it so would probably involve using map or somesuch, but not the assignment statement itself. And no, there's no difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use sigilless containers:

```
my (\a, \b) := 17,42;
say a.VAR.^name; # Int
```

Sigilless variables [do not have an associated container](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-%5C_%28sigilless_variables%29)

Comment: Interestingly, if I use `my (\a, \b) = 17, 42` (assignment, not binding), then `say a.VAR.^name` prints `Scalar`. What happens there?

Comment: [:=] my \a, my \b, 17 #Cannot reduce with := because list assignment operators are too 
fiddly